# Colorbar: Test size of powers in scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am creating a 2D plot with a colorbar. The values in the colorbar are very small, therefore I am using scientific notation. When I want to change the tick sizes of the colorbar the size of text which gives the information about the power of the colorbar is not adjusted. How can I change this?

Here is a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.random.rand(100)*0.001

x=x.reshape((10,10))

y=y.reshape((10,10))

z=z.reshape((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))


cs = ax.contourf(x,y,z, 10)

plt.xticks(fontsize=16,rotation=0)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16,rotation=0)

cbar = plt.colorbar(cs,)
cbar.set_label("test",fontsize = 22)


cbar.formatter.set_scientific(True)
cbar.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
cbar.update_ticks()  

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

which produces the following output:

[image: output of the code]

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired output is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think to change the fontsize of "1e-3" at the top of the colorbar

Comment: Hi thanks for the link. It is actually no duplicate, because here I want to change the offsetText of the colorbar. Something like cbar.ax.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(32) does not work

Comment: @janschütte-engel `cbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(32)` works

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now

Comment: @DavidG Please consider making an answer out of your comment (as it is a good solution) so others would more easily find it.